# How to see all values in a column that are not numeric (ISNUMERIC() equivalent?)

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column that has string and float values, and I only want to select the string values.

In SQL Server I could use `SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE ISNUMERIC(Column) = 0`

But I'm unsure of how to do this in BigQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options would be to use [SAFE_CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_casting):

```
SELECT Column 
FROM Table 
WHERE SAFE_CAST(Column AS INT64) IS NULL
```